# How to handle common mispronunciations in Alexa Custom Slot Type

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Amazon Alexa skill that uses a custom slot to allow the user to specify one of 82 values (a county).  One of the values is "Hinds", but she is hearing "Heinz" and reporting that to my service.  I understand that in some cases this is "by design" and that the user can say other things, but in this case I want to automatically correct this common mispronunciation. Heinz will never be valid.  Should I just do this in the code or is there a better way to configure this within the developer console.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is no ambiguity in this case: when you get 'Heinz' you know that they said 'Hinds', so I would just manually convert 'Heinz' to 'Hinds' in your skill.

There is no better way (that I know of) to handle this.

I'm a bit surprised that Alexa would be reporting 'Heinz' to you when your custom slot word list includes 'Hinds' and not 'Heinz' but I think there is no harm, and perhaps it will stop happening as Amazon improves its speech recognition.

Comment: I wonder if custom lists mean anything to Alexa. I have small lists returning all types of values. I've debated building a grammar engine (e.g. SRGS) that supports the ability to find the best match.